# How can I avoid duplication name in react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a user profile page component and in that page I have list of friends.

When I click on friend icon I route to friend page which use the same profile page component just render different info which get by id.

I did routes but if I will pass a few time to different friends I have the url like "`user/user/user/1`".

So if I route one time I have `/user/1` and if I route one more time to another user I expected the link to be `user/2` but I have `user/user/2`.
How can I fix this issue?

Link that **routes** to the user is inside a return of **map** function:

```
{friends.map((friendInfo, id) => 
  return(
    <Link to={`user/${friends.id}`} >
    </Link>
   );
})}
```

Routes

```
    <Route path="/" exact component={Profile} />
    <Route path="/user/:id" component={Profile} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do to achieve your desired functionality:
At first you can check if URl contains **/user** then don,t route to user and else go to **/user**. You can use **withRouter** or params to make get URl values.

**For Example:**

```
{friends.map((friendInfo, id) => 
  return(
    <Link to={url.includes('user')?`/${friends.id}`: `user/${friends.id}`} > 
     //do conditional rendering above to Link
    </Link>
   );
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the render of `friends` array you should add back slash to your `Link` url

```
{friends.map((friendInfo, id) => 
  return(
    <Link to={`/user/${friends.id}`} > {/* <--- here add back slash */}
    </Link>
   );
})}
```